# Php mysql query charset

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have problem with query charset for mysql bd in php script.

I'm placing `GET` parameter inside `select` query and it work good for all Latin characters, but with Cyrillic characters it returns me empty table. If I place some value with Cyrillic in query instead of `GET` parameter, query works as I want. Likewise, I get result query inside php-Admin and it works.

All Cyrillic characters in result shows me correct.

I've checked everything: php-file is `utf8`, `GET` parameter value is `utf8`, `mysql_client_encoding()` returns me `utf8`.

I've tried all I found - nothing helps me.

```
header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $link);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $link);
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'", $link);
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $link);
```

All of this **DOESN'T HELP**.

Here is my php script.

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'r96036lg_searche', 'Jh1ZT4]^');
    //mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
    //mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $link);
    //mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $link);
    //mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'", $link);
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $link);
    //echo mysql_client_encoding($link);
    mysql_select_db('r96036lg_searche', $link);
    //mysqli::set_charset('utf8');
    $query = "select id, name, typeid from MainObjects where used = 1";
    if(isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])) {
        //$name = mb_convert_encoding($_GET['name'], "UTF-8", "win1251");
        $name = $_GET['name'];
        //echo mb_detect_encoding($name, "auto", false);
        //$name = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($name, "auto", false), "UTF-8", $name);
        //echo $name;
        $query .= " and typeid = 1 and (name like '%".$name.
                "%' or id in (select parentid from MainObjects where name like '%"
                .$name."%' and used = 1))";
    }
    //echo $query;
    $result = mysql_query($query, $link);
    if(!$result) echo mysql_error();
    else {
        $out = "[";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            ... //here is myoutput
        }
        $out .= "]";
        echo $out;
  }
?>
```

Comment: You didn't escape the $_GET parameter before injecting it into the query. Do you know about SQL Injection ? If not, read about it before you proceed.

Comment: It looks like you generate some JSON. If that's true, use `json_encode` instead.

Comment: What do you get when you `echo $query);` ? Did you already try to run this in phpmyadmin ?

Comment: Yes, I know about injections. Now it is not important. @LorenzMeyer

Comment: `JSON` used only for output - there is no problem with it. And yes, I've tried it in phpadmin - it works. @LorenzMeyer

Comment: Try `mysql_real_escape_string` as below. If it doesn't work post here for an example the values of `$_GET['name']`, `$query` and `mysql_error()`.

Comment: name - `к`; 
query - `select id, name, typeid from MainObjects where used = 1 and typeid = 1 and (name like '%к%' or id in (select parentid from MainObjects where name like '%к%' and used = 1))`;
mysql_error() is empty;
result is empty

Comment: Move away from the deprecated mysql_* interface to mysqli_*.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- it sounds like the column(s) are latin1 instead of utf8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do it. It will not solve the caracter encoding thing, but it will help with the reste. (And perhaps even solve your problem, because it might just be related to not escaping the values).

```
$query = "select id, name, typeid from MainObjects where used = 1";
if(isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
    $query .= " and typeid = 1 and (name like '%".$name.
            "%' or id in (select parentid from MainObjects where name like '%"
            .$name."%' and used = 1))";
}
//echo $query;
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
```

I this does not help there is a character coding mismatch somewhere. There are three points:

- GET data: did you try to encode the url like `example.com/index.php?name=%d0%ba` (cyrillic small letter ka)
- communication with server. If you did really try all you said, there should not be an error
- data in the tables: Does the collation of the table really correspond to its content. What I might suspect is that there is a mismatch. If the data is in UTF-8, but the table isn't, mysql will try to convert the data from one character set into another, and as a result it will not much.

Comment: You didn't post the data I asked for. I don't have your data. I can't test.

Comment: With your `name` parameter value it works. How did you convert it? And table field is `utf8` too.

Comment: `%d0%ba` is the standard url encoding for a Cyrillic ka. This means that your `$_GET` value is not encoded in utf8. Normally, if the originating html page is encoded in utf8, the form data will be encoded also in utf8.

Comment: Well, it works. I used `URLEncoder` in my java app to send correct `GET` value. Thanks, you helped me.